# In Excel, can I make a data table have different data to the chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to add a table to a chart in MS Excel. I have looked at other answers, and they all seem to not quite do what I want to do, which is why I am posting here.

My data looks like this:

[image: Data]

I wish to show the % completion of tasks as a stacked bar chart, with a table underneath showing whether the task is on track for this completion date, and its estimated end date. Something like this:

[image: Chart]

but with the chart instead showing completion date and the end date. Another answer forum suggested pasting the table, but this still keeps the original data, which makes the table hard to read:

[image: Pasted data]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to experiment I did the following:

- Type a list similar to yours, select any cell(s) in the list, Ctrl+T to make a 'table'
- Select somewhere in the table, then Insert, 2-D bar, stacked 100%

The result looks like this, would it be suitable? (Completion Date is listed on the vertical axis, after the Activity label.)

[image]